# SQLite : Where with multiple conditions and index

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, database-performance, sqlperformance

I am facing some troubles with indexing my SQLite database.

Background :
I have databases that can be query on each columns, all are TEXT COLLATE NOCASE, all conditions are "LIKE ***%", the database is in no case sensitive like, the page size is 32768
My databases are read only, i fill them up one time with an import csv scripts. After that, no modifications.
I execute after all the creation (database, table, import, index) : ANALYZE and PRAGMA optimize

I try create an index on each columns (I don't care about the size of my database).

For exemple, with a column_a_index

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE column_a LIKE "A%";
```

is quick.

But, with a column_a_index, column_b_index, column_c_index

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE column_a LIKE "A%" AND column_b LIKE "B%" AND column_c LIKE "C%";
```

is slower than

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table NOT INDEXED WHERE column_a LIKE "A%" AND column_b LIKE "B%" AND column_c LIKE "C%";
```

If i create a column_a_b_c_index, the request is fast.

In few words : If the index matches exactly the conditions, the request is fast. If the index doesn't match perfectly the conditions, the request is slower thant a request without any index !

- Do I have to create indexes for all possible combinations ?
- I use "SELECT MAX(*ROWID*) FROM my_table;" instead of "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table;" when there is no condition, because there is NO modifications of my table after the initial import. Do you have any others tips for read only databases ?
- I use "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;", "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;" and "PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE;"
- Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer focuses on your second query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE column_a LIKE 'A%' AND column_b LIKE 'B%' AND column_c LIKE 'C%';
```

The index which would be appropriate for this query would cover all three columns in the `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON my_table (column_a, column_b, column_c);
```

Three separate indices on the A, B, and C columns would likely not be used by SQLite.  Actually, the index I suggested above might also not be used, but it would be the best bet for this query.

Comment: I'm agree with you, but the issue is that have 10 columns and the query field are variables. So i have to create all the combinations ?

Comment: Are you saying that you expect a `LIKE` clause which might involve 10 possible combinations of columns?

Comment: What i'm saying is the requests can be on one column, two columns, three columns,... I don't know,it's the visitors they choose.